# Chrome extension How to generate transition type "keyword_generated"

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Ï am developing a chrome extension to track transition types as per https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history but unable to generate keyword_generated transition type so that can test my code.
Plesae help to find out steps to produce  "keyword_generated" transition type

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/ui/base/page_transition_types.h?l=88&rcl=202930499e5efc7bddb88f4a382a1b6be1d61d02):

> The url was generated from a replaceable keyword other than the default
>   search provider. If the user types a keyword (which also applies to
>   tab-to-search) in the omnibox this qualifier is applied to the transition
>   type of the generated url. TemplateURLModel then may generate an
>   additional visit with a transition type of KEYWORD_GENERATED against the
>   url 'http://' + keyword. For example, if you do a tab-to-search against
>   wikipedia the generated url has a transition qualifer of KEYWORD, and
>   TemplateURLModel generates a visit for 'wikipedia.org' with a transition
>   type of KEYWORD_GENERATED.